# Depending on inherited test

Tags: php, inheritance, phpunit

I have two classes, Parent and Child:

```
class Parent
{
    public function parentAction() {...}
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public function childAction() {...}
}
```

Now I am testing these with PHPUnit. (I'm not truly unit-testing, but for the purpose of the question, I guess you could assume that I am. I do this with these test classes:

```
abstract class ParentBaseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testParentAction() {...}

    protected function factoryMethod() 
    {
        return new Parent();
    }
}

class ParentTest extends ParentBaseTest
{
}

class ChildTest  extends ParentBaseTest
{
    protected function factoryMethod()
    {
        return new Child();
    }

    public function testChildAction() {...}
}
```

The idea behind using inheritance here with the factoryMethod is that without rewriting the tests for Parent, the tests from ParentBaseTest will also be run on Child. In other words, the test is whether Child properly adheres to the Liskov substitution principle. The use of an abstract base class and an empty inheriting class is necessary because PHPUnit doesn't feel like running your base class tests twice otherwise.

The above all works. However, now I want to add a dependency on `testParentAction()` to `testChildAction()` (i.e. add `/** @depends testParentAction */` before the `testChildAction()` definition).

This does not work. Because PHPUnit doesn't alter the order in which tests are run to satisfy dependencies and runs the tests defined in `ChildTest` before running the tests it inherited from `ParentTest`, it will just always cause `testChildMethod()` to be skipped.

Is it possible to force PHPUnit to run the inherited tests first? Or is there perhaps another (clean) way to enforce the dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding about unit testing here. While your OOP theory is accurate it's not well applied to the realm of the unit testing, let me explain my points.

Each test case class is supposed to test all the behaviour of a given class and each test case inside that class is supposed to test a small part of each method in the tested class. This means that it makes no sense to have a factory method inside the test classes as it should never vary or receive a different instance to test or it will be testing the wrong things for that class. In the setup you can instantiate the shared fixture and the Child or Parent class are shared among all test cases of their respective test classes.

Also unit test cases are supposed to run isolated, so you can freely run a given test case and it should pass and no other test case should depend of this result to pass or fail or you'll have a random behaviour in your test which is never a good thing. So Child test should not depend of the test of the Parent and Parent should not depend of the test of the Child (Even in OOP a parent class should be ignorant of its childs).

Additionally test cases can run in a different order and this shouldn't affect the correctness of the testing because as I said, each test case should be able to run isolated.

If you want to read more about how to do good unit testing I strongly recommend this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Unit-Testing-guide-Developers/dp/1935182579/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1372014749&sr=8-3&keywords=unit+testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182579) it is targeted for java developers but theory is shared among all frameworks and they have a full section of testing smells and how to fix them and prevent them.

Comment: @Jasper: I think you misread markdrake and also you misunderstand something even more basic: Nobody here needs to explain you anything. I would word this different saying that you were not able to understand the answer. So it's less about an ideal or not so ideal world, but really more about what has been answered: Both unit-tests need to test both types on their own. Period. Run the tests isolated to test those objects. If there is a hidden dependency between those two types, fix that. That's why you test.

Comment: @hakre You are absolutely right about my wording and tone. I'll reword my comment(s).

Comment: As I see it, following the Liskov substitution principle, you should be able to run the tests that you wrote for your parent class on your child class as well. You say it makes no sense to use a factory method for that, but what I do not understand is how a factory method would lead to testing the wrong things. I also don't understand why there can't be dependencies between tests. When you test something that uses functionality you're testing as well, marking this test skipped if the original testing of the used functionality fails, means you can better pinpoint the problem with your code.